# tkinter: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to make program to calculate gas prices, but my code gets an error.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
ment = StringVar()

root.geometry('450x450+500+300')
root.title('ბენზმთვლელი')


mlabel2 = Label(root, text='რეგულარი >> '+2.23+ 'GEL').pack()
mlabel3 = Label(root , text = 'ევრო რეგულარი >> '+2.29+' GEL').pack()
mlabel4 = Label(root, text="პრემიუმი >> " + 3.35 + " GEL").pack()
mlabel5 = Label(root, text='დიზელი >> ' + 2.25 + ' GEL').pack()
mlabel6 = Label(root, text='ევრო დიზელი >> '+2.33+' GEL').pack()

mlabel1 = Label(root, text="მიუთითეთ ბენზინის რაოდენობა(ლიტრებში)").pack()
mentry1 = Entry().pack()

mlabel7 = Label(root, text="მიუთითეთ ბენზინის დასახელება(ზემოთ ჩამოთვლილთაგან)").pack()
mentry2 = Entry().pack()

def gamotvla():
    if mlabel7 == mlabel3 or mlabel2 or mlabel4 or mlabel5 or mlabel6:
        print(mlabel1*mlabel7)
    else:
        print('რაღაც შეიყვანე შეცდომით!!')

mbutton = Button(root, text='გამოთვლა',fg="red",bg='black', command=gamotvla).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Error:

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/zura12337/Desktop/Python/Atom/tk.py", line 11, in <module>
    mlabel2 = Label(root, text='რეგულარი >> '+2.23+ 'GEL').pack()
TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects
```

Can you help me?

Comment: Hi there, what do you take away from the following error message?

`TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'float' objects`.

Additionally, this is just a Python problem and has nothing to do with Atom.

Comment: Yes it's mine .

Comment: Why are you adding a number to a string? What do you think that is supposed to do?

Comment: I know that is not true , but i dont know how to fix it :D

Comment: we can't help tell you how to fix it until we know what you want to do. What do you think `'რეგულარი >> '+2.23+ 'GEL'` does? Are you trying to create a single string like `'რეგულარი >> 2.23GEL'`?

Comment: I already fixed it. now i have nother problem

Answer (score 1):

This one line is more than enough to cause the problem:

```
text='რეგულარი >> '+2.23+ 'GEL'
```

`2.23` is a floating-point value; `'GEL'` is a string.  What does it mean to add an arithmetic value and a string of letters?

If you want the string label `'რეგულარი >> 2.23 GEL'`, then write it just that way.  If you want to construct it from the parts, then convert the value to string:

```
text = 'რეგულარი >> ' + str(2.23) + 'GEL'
```

Comment: Hey ,there is one more problem ! :D

Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1544, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "/home/zura12337/Desktop/Python/Atom/tk.py", line 25, in gamotvla
    print(mlabel1*mlabel7)
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for *: 'NoneType' and 'NoneType'

Comment: (1) That's a separate problem; (2) What have you done to resolve it? ///  Please read and follow the posting guidelines in the help documentation.  Post the [Minimal, complete, verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) as a separate question ... *after* you have searched for the root cause: you're getting `None` as a return value from `Label`, code you did not supply.

Answer (score -1):

Let's look at the line in question, and identify a few problems with it.
Here is the line:

```
mlabel2 = Label(root, text='რეგულარი >> '+2.23+ 'GEL').pack()
```

You are concatenating a string, a float, and another string. Easiest way to get around this is with some string format expression, like

```
mlabel2 = Label(root, text='რეგულარი >> {num} GEL'.format(num=2.23))
```

That would be a good solution for Python 3 code... Note that `{num}` is a formatting command that gets replaced with your float. There are other ways to handle this, but since you're using Python 3, I would go with that one. Plus since that number changes in your different Labels, I kept it separate so it's easy to work with.

Also, keep in mind that your **mlabel2** is going to be *None* in your code, because of the `.pack()` command, which returns *None*. If you want to preserve **mlabel2**, you have to break the statement up into two...

```
mlabel2 = Label(root, .... GEL')
mlabel2.pack()
```

This is the same for most all of your widgets, including the Label's, Entry's, and Button.  The `if` statement in your `def gamotvla():` is also going to cause you problems, but let's start with these.